# Add filter scripts to react app that is using routes?

Tags: reactjs

I am building a react app that is using routes. To better work on a single "page", I use a code playground to mess with the code and aim to implement it into the final react app. However using routes complicates things and I want to know how to implement the script I know works. In the single page react app, my index.js (last snippet) checks elements in the html of one page (the 2 div's in the first code snippet) and will render components (second code snippet) based off the conditional. On my final react app, having multiple of these pages, I am not sure where or how to include the script, as the html document it uses is, itself, a component (first snippet).

```
//This div is the component that, on click, applies a component to be returned via jsx function. This is a component called ExercisesLauncher.jsx
            <div id="Gym/Home/Upper/Lower/Cardio" class="col-lg-4 d-flex align-items-stretch">
              <div
                style={cursorPointer}
                class="card w-100 mb-4 rounded-3 shadow-sm filter"
              >
                <div class="card-heading py-1">
                  <h1 class="normal-heading">Gym/Home/Upper/Lower/Cardio</h1>
                </div>
                <div class="card-body">
                  <p>You have equipment that is found at an ordinary gym.</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>


//This div is created later in the same file, loading UpperLevel component, root was originally used in the html file (single page) to load components seen later in the question.
          <div id="root" class="container">
            <UpperLevel />
          </div>
```

```
//This is the component that is to be loaded, and included are the other components I wish to swap out depending on if a div is clicked. UpperLevel is used in the ExercisesLauncher component
import React from "react";
import Grid from "./Grid";
import GridCardio from "./GridCardio";
import GridGym from "./GridGym";
import GridHome from "./GridHome";
import GridUpper from "./GridUpper";
import GridLower from "./GridLower";

function UpperLevel() {
  return (
    <div class="album py-5 container">
      <GridCardio />
    </div>
  );
}

export default UpperLevel;
```

```
//This code was used for the single page not using routes, in the playground, the DOM references refer to the divs above, that are now in a .jsx file, not an HTML file
var gym = document.getElementById("Gym");
var home = document.getElementById("Home");
var upper = document.getElementById("Upper");
var lower = document.getElementById("Lower");
var cardio = document.getElementById("Cardio");

document.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
  if (gym.contains(event.target)) {
    ReactDOM.render(<GridGym />, document.getElementById("root"));
  } else if (home.contains(event.target)) {
    ReactDOM.render(<GridHome />, document.getElementById("root"));
  } else if (upper.contains(event.target)) {
    ReactDOM.render(<GridUpper />, document.getElementById("root"));
  } else if (lower.contains(event.target)) {
    ReactDOM.render(<GridLower />, document.getElementById("root"));
  } else if (cardio.contains(event.target)) {
    ReactDOM.render(<GridCardio />, document.getElementById("root"));
  } else {
    ReactDOM.render(<Grid />, document.getElementById("root"));
  }
});
```

[image: ExercisesLauncher being used in App2 component]
[image: Routes being used showing App2 component]

So far, I tried to paste the script inside the ExercisesLauncher component, as well as importing the necessary components, but the corresponding path just loads a white screen.

Comment: My current thought/solution is to used grid in the upper level instead! On click's will simply change the <Grid/> value, aka, where UpperLevel is. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it:

```
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";

function Grid() {
  const routes = [
    { path: "", name: "Gym", element: <GridGym /> },
    { path: "home", name: "Home", element: <GridHome /> },
    { path: "upper", name: "Upper", element: <GridUpper /> },
    { path: "lower", name: "Lower", element: <GridLower /> },
    { path: "cardio", name: "Cardio", element: <GridCardio /> }
  ];
  return (
    <>
      <nav>
        {routes.map((route) => (
          <Link to={route.path} key={route.path}>
            Grid{route.name}
          </Link>
        ))}
      </nav>
      <Routes>
        {routes.map((route) => (
          <Route {...route} key={route.path} />
        ))}
      </Routes>
    </>
  );
}

function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <nav>
        <Link to="/">Home</Link>
        <Link to="grid/">Grid</Link>
      </nav>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
        <Route path="grid/*" element={<Grid />} />
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
```

I removed the irrelevant parts (e.g imports, etc...).
A full working example here: https://codesandbox.io/s/hungry-davinci-bgmswd?file=/src/App.js

Main takeaway: in React you don't check DOM. DOM renders according to model: you change the model and DOM reflects the change.

Comment: This will help tremendously, thank you. I assume this would be inside my index,js?

Comment: @joseistired, typically each component would be a function and would be the default export of a single file. I crammed them all into App.js for brevity. Except for the App function (which goes into App.js), the above would be the `Grid.js` and `function Grid()` should be prefixed with `export default`.

Comment: In the sandbox, I used the `Mock` function to create shallow components from strings, dynamically. In a real app you'd import each component from its own file.

Comment: Hello, I am not sure if it is worth your time, but I was able to come up with a solution of my own if you care to check it out, I appreciate your guidance however!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using unnecesarry components, I simply used the jsx code inside the App2 component that is used directly in my index file. I came up with a script that rerenders my grid component upon function call, which is triggered via click. I simply used hooks, useState, to do what I needed to do. Much easier than I thought!

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';

import {render} from 'react-dom';
import NavBar from "./components/NavBar";
import Grid from "./components/Exercises/Grid";
import GridCardio from "./components/Exercises/GridCardio";
import GridHome from "./components/Exercises/GridHome";
import GridGym from "./components/Exercises/GridGym";
import GridUpper from "./components/Exercises/GridUpper";
import GridLower from "./components/Exercises/GridLower";

const marginAuto = {
  margin: "auto"
};
const cursorPointer = {
  cursor: "pointer"
};

//THIS IS ALL RESPONSIBLE FOR LOADING EVERYTHING IN ONE PAGE DONT WORRY ABOUT IT
function App2() {
  // const [display, setState] = React.useState(<Grid/>);
  let component = <Grid/>;
  const [gridState, changePlease] = useState(component);

  function applyHome(){
    changePlease(<GridHome/>);
  }
  function applyCardio(){
    changePlease(<GridCardio/>);
  }
  function applyLower(){
    changePlease(<GridLower/>);
  }
  function applyUpper(){
    changePlease(<GridUpper/>);
  }
  function applyHome(){
    changePlease(<GridHome/>);
  }
  function applyGym(){
    changePlease(<GridGym/>);
  }

  return (<section>
    <NavBar/>

    <main>
      <section class="colored-section" id="title">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="container-fluid main-text">
              <h1 class="big-heading">Exercises</h1>
              <p>
                Below, feel free to navigate to whatever execrises you may find useful for your next workout. Either learn more about the exercise, or add it to your catelog to later add to your scheduler.
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>

          <h2 class="normal-heading mb-4">Group</h2>
          <div class="container-fluid row row-cols-1 row-cols-md-3 mb-3 text-center" style={marginAuto}>
            <div id="Gym" class="col-lg-6 d-flex align-items-stretch">
              <div style={cursorPointer} onClick={applyGym} class="card w-100 mb-4 rounded-3 shadow-sm filter">
                <div class="card-heading py-1">
                  <h1 class="normal-heading">Gym</h1>
                </div>
                <div class="card-body">
                  <p>You have equipment that is found at an ordinary gym.</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

              <div id="Home" class="col-lg-6 d-flex align-items-stretch">
                <div style={cursorPointer} onClick={applyHome}  class="card w-100 mb-4 rounded-3 shadow-sm filter">
                  <div class="card-heading py-1">
                    <h1 class="normal-heading">At Home</h1>
                  </div>
                  <div class="card-body">
                    <p>
                      Small, mobile, or convenient equipment that still has use.
                    </p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>

          </div>

          <h2 class="normal-heading mb-4">Equipment</h2>
          <div class="container-fluid row row-cols-1 row-cols-md-3 mb-3 text-center" style={marginAuto}>

            <div id="Upper" class="col-lg-4 d-flex align-items-stretch">
              <div style={cursorPointer} onClick={applyUpper}  class="card w-100 mb-4 rounded-3 shadow-sm filter">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <h1 class="normal-heading">Upper Body</h1>
                  <p>
                    Includes the chest, arms, shoulders, and anything else above the waist.
                  </p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div id="Lower" class="col-lg-4 d-flex align-items-stretch">
              <div style={cursorPointer} onClick={applyLower} class="card w-100 mb-4 rounded-3 shadow-sm filter">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <h1 class="normal-heading">Lower Body</h1>
                  <p>
                    Includes the quadriceps, hamstrings, glutes, and anything else below the waist.
                  </p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div id="Cardio" onClick={applyCardio} class="col-lg-4 d-flex align-items-stretch">
              <div style={cursorPointer}  class="card w-100 mb-4 rounded-3 shadow-sm filter">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <h1 class="normal-heading">Cardio</h1>
                  <p>
                    Any exercise that benefits the cardio-system that gets the heart pumpin.
                  </p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>
      </section>

      <section>
        <div class="album py-5 black-section">
          <div id="root" class="container">
            {/* THIS WILL CHANGE BASED ON CLICKS */}
             {gridState}
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>

      <footer id="footer">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <a href="index.html">
            {" "}
            <img class="logo mb-3" src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/fabianenavarro/Get-a-Grip/main/public/images/fist.png" alt=""/>
          </a>
          <p>2022 Getta Grip! LLC</p>
        </div>
      </footer>

    </main>);
  </section>);
}

export default App2;
```